# How to plot function over interval returned by Reduce[]

Tags: plotting, intervals

Let $f(x) = (x^2 + 1) / x$. I need to plot the function for the values of $x$ in which the square of the function is larger than 4, and its cube is smaller than 64. So I used `Reduce` like this:

```
Reduce[((x^2 + 1)/x)^2 > 4 && ((x^2 + 1)/x)^3 < 64, x, Reals]
```

Now I am having problems plotting this. I need to use `Plot` to display the function on the specific interval, but I do not know how to input the result from `Reduce` (which may be union of intervals) in `Plot` in order to draw the function only for those values of $x$. Could anyone assist?

Comment: Given that $x\le -1$ all satisfy your constraint (the squares are large and positive while the cubes are large and negative, whence less than $64$), how do you propose handling that infinite extent in the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your conditions directly with `ConditionalExpression` without going through `Reduce`:

```
  Plot[ConditionalExpression[(x^2 + 1)/ x,
    ((x^2 + 1)/x)^2 > 4 && ((x^2 + 1)/x)^3 < 64], {x, -3, 3}]
```

gives

[image]

Similarly, you get the same result using `Piecewise`:

```
 Plot[Piecewise[{{(x^2 + 1)/x,  ((x^2 + 1)/x)^2 > 4 && ((x^2 + 1)/x)^3 < 64}}, 
       Indeterminate], {x, -3, 3}]
```

If have to use `Reduce`, it can be used with `ConditionalExpression` and `Piecewise` as follows:

```
  Plot[Evaluate@ConditionalExpression[(x^2 + 1)/x, 
     Reduce[((x^2 + 1)/x)^2 > 4 && ((x^2 + 1)/x)^3 < 64, x, Reals]], {x, -3, 3}]
  Plot[Evaluate@Piecewise[{{(x^2 + 1)/x,
    Reduce[((x^2 + 1)/x)^2 > 4 && ((x^2 + 1)/x)^3 < 64, x, Reals]}},
     Indeterminate], {x, -3, 3}]
```

Both give the same output as above.

Answer (score 2):

**There are two subproblems**: finding a reasonable plot range and restricting the graph to a subset of that range.

The following is somewhat brute force, but it is clear and general.  It begins in the same way, by defining the function to plot (because it will be invoked several times):

```
f[x_] := (x^2 + 1)/x
```

We will also invoke the constraints twice, so let's put them into a function, too:

```
g[x_] := f[x]^2 > 4 && f[x]^3 < 64
```

(`Reduce` could be used here to speed up future calls to `g`, but it is not necessary.  In other cases `Reduce` could fail to find a solution, so avoiding it provides a more general approach to plotting.)

We use numerical methods to find a *finite* plotting interval because there's no point to getting exact symbolic solutions for a plot.  The idea is to maximize and minimize $x$ subject to the constraints, but limiting the search to an interval to make sure that finite endpoints are obtained:

```
xlim = x /. Last[#[{x, g[x], -10 <= x <= 10}, x]] & /@ {NMinimize, NMaximize}
```

Assemble this information into the plot:

```
Plot[If[g[x], f[x]], Evaluate @ {x, Sequence @@ xlim}]
```

[image: Plot]

In principle, the left limit of this plot should be $-\infty$; it was truncated at $-10$ by the interval constraints provided to `NMaximize` and `NMinimize`.  Without that truncation the plot could not be created.